# How do a drag in a toolbar to a uitableview with storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a tableview and I want to put a tool bar on the top but when I drag in on it just it won't take the tool bar like it does with a regular uiview.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inserting a toolbar insert a navigation bar. A toolbar is supposed to be on the bottom and the navigation bar is supposed to be on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Using a navigationController is probably what you really want. If you choose your viewController, then go to Editor > Embed In > Navigation Conroller - this will add it for you.

Bear in mind though that you might not actually want to do this on the specific viewController you are talking about here; you might want to do it, for example, on the first viewController displayed in your app (or another logical beginning for a navigationController), then if you use push segues to some other viewControllers, you'll notice that they will inherit the navigationBar at the top of the screen (as well as some other stuff for free, like the back button).

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Comment: no. i commonly use toolbars at the top, but for some reason it does not work this time. don't know why